# googlescript spreadsheet not updating on exec

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, exec

When I published the app, in dev mode the spreadsheet is getting updated, but in exec mode it is not, even though the spreadsheet has all the permission for any anonymous to edit it.

```
    //Code.js:
    function doGet(e) {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html')
        .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the NATIVE mode
        .setTitle('Name To Appear in Browser Tab')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    }

    function processForm(theForm) {
       var fileBlob = theForm.picToLoad;
        var fldrSssn = DocsList.getFolder('For Web Hosting');
        var createdFile = fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
        var fileUrl = createdFile.getUrl();
        var name = theForm.user_name;
        var files = DocsList.find('prat');// this is an array of file objects that include the term 'thisisthesheetIwant'
        var file = files[0];// I take the first one
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);// using that file object I can open a spreadsheet
        var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];


      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[name,fileUrl]]);
      return true;


    }
```

Comment: I've added javascript to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't re-published a new version, it will keep running the old version in exec mode. Dev mode runs the current version. Exec mode runs the last published version